# The Facebook Flux documentation states there are "no two-way data bindings" - does this mean what it says?

Tags: javascript, flux

The Facebook Flux documentation states there are "no two-way data bindings" - does this mean what it says?

Presumably I **can** build a two-way data binding with Flux?

Reference: see section *Structure and Data Flow*, https://facebook.github.io/flux/docs/overview.html#content

Answer (score 0):

One of the key principle of Flux is its one-way data-flow. They believe that two-way bindings lead to a mess of dependent code (my free translation).
(An article on [AEflash blog](http://aeflash.com/2015-02/react-tips-and-best-practices.html) gives some further background).

In essence, you are not supposed to do this:
[image: Two-way binding]

But flux prescribes that you do this instead:
[image]

To maintain one-way data flow.

PS: You probably can do two-way binding in a flux architecture. See also [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33217799/how-would-one-do-two-day-data-binding-in-react-having-an-input-value-a-update-w/33218275#33218275) to see it implemented inside one component. But generally speaking