# How would one do two day data binding in React, having an input value A update when B is and vice versa, while keeping history of previous transforms?

Tags: javascript, data-binding, reactjs, transformation

The following code for data binding:

```
var Text = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function(){
  return {
      pageName: this.props.pageName,
      url:  this.props.pageName,
  }
},
handleChange: function(event){
  var pageName = event.target.value;
  var url      = event.target.value.toLowerCase();
  this.setState({
      pageName: pageName,
      url: url,
          });
},
render: function() {
  return (
      <div>
      pageName: <input ref="pageName" onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.pageName}/><br/>
    url: <input ref="url" onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.url}/><br/>
    </div>);
  }
});

React.render(<Text pageName="name" />, document.body);
```

A live demo can be see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/k5d6jhhb/35/). However, being that React re-renders after every input, the toLowerCase() function only picks up on the last letter. How would I make it so that it remembers the previous state(not looking for a slice()/splice() workaround, if possible). Thanks in advance!

Comment: I guess I don't understand your problem.  What part of your demo isn't working the way you want it to?  Also, `this.state.url` technically is the previous state, considering you are updating it in your `handleChange` function.  Why not use that?

Comment: Thanks for asking :). The issue is that when putting capital letters into url, only the last capital letter will make it's way to PageName, as opposed to all of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add an id to the inputs to be able to determine where the input came from when `handleChange` is run. And then make sure that all input into url is always translated to Lowercase when you update pageName. E.g.

```
var Text = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function(){
      return {
          pageName: this.props.pageName,
          url:  this.props.pageName,
      }
  },
  handleChange: function(event){
      var pageName = event.target.value;
      // ADDED EXTRA LINE HERE
      pageName = (event.target.id == "url") ? pageName.toLowerCase() : pageName;
      var url      = event.target.value.toLowerCase();
      this.setState({
          pageName: pageName,
          url: url,
              });
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
        <div>
        pageName: <input ref="pageName" onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.pageName}/><br/>
        url: <input ref="url" id="url"onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.url}/><br/>
        </div>);
  }
});

React.render(<Text pageName="name" />, document.body);
```

You CANNOT however do two-way binding between both fields AND maintain all CAPS typed in name AND transform url to lowercase.

Comment: My apologies, please see my comment above. This is currently not doing what I originally had in mind. http://jsfiddle.net/k5d6jhhb/37/. Thanks!

Comment: I see. What you are looking for is not possible/ much more complicated. When your url is always all lowercase, then that's what will be copied to pageName. To maintain what was originally caps requires more complicated comparison of input in url, comparing with original pageName with caps, and then updating pageName with the difference. The simple way out would be to have only 1 input field pageName, and to update url always with lowercase version of pageName.